# How can I add a second row of labels to the x axis of a matplotllib bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Pandas dataframe that records time using 'quarter' and 'year', something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

myDF = pd.DataFrame({'quarter':['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'],
                     'year':[2018,2018,2018,2018,2019,2019,2019,2019,2020,2020,2020,2020],
                     'data':[2,3,4,3,4,5,6,5,6,7,8,7,8,9,10,9]})
```

which looks like:

```
    year quarter  data
0   2018      Q1     2
1   2018      Q2     3
2   2018      Q3     4
3   2018      Q4     3
4   2019      Q1     4
5   2019      Q2     5
6   2019      Q3     6
7   2019      Q4     5
8   2020      Q1     6
9   2020      Q2     7
10  2020      Q3     8
11  2020      Q4     7
```

I can plot a bar chart of 'data' against 'quarter' using:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rects = ax.bar(np.arange(len(myDF['quarter'])),
               myDF['data'],
               width = 0.8,
               )
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(myDF['quarter'])))
ax.set_xticklabels(myDF['quarter'])

plt.show()
```

The plot appears as:

[image: ![Bar chart with plotting data against quarter]

I want to be able to add an extra row to the x axis that gives the year, either with the year aligned left so the year value appears directly below Q1 or aligned middle so the year value appears below the mid-point between Q2 and Q3.

Comment: yearlocator could help. did you check this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428729/matplotlib-dates-yearlocator-with-odd-intervals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation, I found a solution that works for me. I included the quarter number (i.e. Q1, Q2, Q3, etc.) as labels for the major ticks but also added the years as labels for minor ticks.

The full solution is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

myDF = pd.DataFrame({'quarter':['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'],
                     'year':[2018,2018,2018,2018,2019,2019,2019,2019,2020,2020,2020,2020],
                     'data':[2,3,4,3,4,5,6,5,6,7,8,7]})
print(myDF[['year','quarter','data']])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rects = ax.bar(np.arange(len(myDF['quarter'])),
               myDF['data'],
               width = 0.8,
               )

# Set major xticks and xlabels - Quarter number
# ----------------------------
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(np.arange(0,len(myDF.index))))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(myDF['quarter']))
ax.tick_params(which='major', length=5)

# Set minor xticks and xlabels - Year
# ----------------------------
# Use list comprehension to find average of index for each subsequent group of 4 items.
# Could use FuncFormatter to define function to calculate position of Year values.
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([np.mean(myArr[i:i+4]) for i in range(0,len(np.arange(0,len(myDF.index))),4)]))
ax.tick_params(which='minor', pad=30)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(myDF['year'].unique()))
# Change font used to display years
for tick in ax.xaxis.get_minor_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(14)
    tick.label.set_fontweight('bold')

plt.show()
```

In the example above, I've used a list comprehension to calculate the mean of blocks of 4 quarters (e.g. positions 0, 1, 2 and 3 are averaged to produce 1.5, etc.). The code to define exactly where the minor ticks appear can be as simple or complex as needed to produce required values.

The resulting graph looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the simplest way would be to change the labels, adding the year to each `Q1`:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects = ax.bar(np.arange(len(myDF['quarter'])), myDF['data'], width=0.8)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(myDF['quarter'])))
ax.set_xticklabels([f'{q}\n{y % 100:02d}' if q == 'Q1' else q 
                    for q, y in zip(myDF['quarter'], myDF['year'])])
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks for the response. This solution could certainly work in some situations but I was hoping to have a bit more flexibility about where the second row labels appear.