# Matplotlib minor ticks don't appear if coincide with major ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

This question relates to the accepted answer to the question at [How can I add a second row of labels to the x axis of a matplotllib bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65656373/how-can-i-add-a-second-row-of-labels-to-the-x-axis-of-a-matplotllib-bar-chart)

The aim was to produce a bar chart where major ticks were labelled with one set of labels (e.g. Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4) whilst the minor ticks were labelled with a different set of labels (e.g. year). In general, the solution works well but if the minor tick locator coincides with the major tick locator then the minor tick label is not displayed.

As an example, the following code works as required:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Plot bars
rects = ax.bar(np.arange(12),[5]*12)

# Set major xticks and xlabels - Quarter number
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(np.arange(0,12)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']*3))
ax.tick_params(which = 'major', length = 5)

# Set minor xticks and xlabels - Year
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([1.5, 5.5, 9.5]))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter([2018,2019,2020]))
ax.tick_params(which='minor', pad=30)

# Change font used to display years
for tick in ax.xaxis.get_minor_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(14)
    tick.label.set_fontweight('bold')

plt.show()
```

[image: Bar chart with correct x axis labels]

However, the following code (where the final minor locator coincides with a major tick) has a missing label.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Plot bars
rects = ax.bar(np.arange(12),[5]*12)

# Set major xticks and xlabels - Quarter number
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(np.arange(0,12)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']*3))
ax.tick_params(which = 'major', length = 5)

# Set minor xticks and xlabels - Year
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([1.5, 5.5, 9.0]))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter([2018,2019,2020]))
ax.tick_params(which='minor', pad=30)

# Change font used to display years
for tick in ax.xaxis.get_minor_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(14)
    tick.label.set_fontweight('bold')

plt.show()
```

[image: Bar chart with missing label]

Is this intended behaviour of the minor tick Locator or should this be reported as a bug?

Comment: Minor ticks are placed in between major ticks. In my opinion, this is the expected behavior.

Comment: @Mr.T That's a good point and I can see that that would certainly make sense when automatically creating minor ticks but I would have thought that FixedLocator would allow users to define locations without restrictions.